# Calling ReactDOM.render more than once

Tags: reactjs

Why does the following only render a single button?

```
const b = <button>this is a button</button>;
ReactDOM.render(b,mountNode)
ReactDOM.render(b,mountNode)
ReactDOM.render(b,mountNode)
```

Comment: Probably because `mountNode` is the same for all of them. Try to change it and check whether it still happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `mountNode` is a reference to a DOM element, calling `ReactDOM.render(b, mountNode)` means that React will insert your React Component as the innerHTML to that node.

Calling it several times effectively means that you just keep replacing the previously mounted node.

If you want 3 buttons, try creating a component that wraps them. For example:

```js
var mountNode = document.getElementById("app");

const b = <button>this is a button</button>;
const myApp = <div>{b}{b}{b}</div>;

ReactDOM.render(myApp, mountNode);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Alternatively:

```js
var mountNode = document.getElementById("app");

const B = () => <button>this is a button</button>;
const MyApp = () => <div><B /><B /><B /></div>;

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, mountNode);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In react it creates virtual DOM. Every time render method is called the previous DOM is replaced by new created DOM. It only looks for difference between previous DOM and new DOM. That's why it renders single button.